# Javascript - generate REST server and HTML client from db schema

Tags: node.js, rest, generics, code-generation

Is there a way to generate REST client and server from a database schema?
Ohh, ofc it is, but are there solutions for that in node.js?

I found flatiron / (restful & resourceful) as a possible solution for REST server generating from schema, but haven't found any tutorial how to use them yet . :S

Haven't found a client generator yet. It could be written with backbone I think.

**I'll start a project to create such generators.**

Comment: Get cracking. I'm pretty sure there isn't a client generator.

Comment: Ye me too... I think it could be written for backbone or extjs, and the server for express-resource or restify. It's complicated, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to map the resources to entities by simple CRUD applications.

By more complicated applications it is not possible, because we map resources combined with HTTP methods to operations. So by more abstract operations we have to define new resources, which cannot be mapped to entities.

The Hydra project has a [symfony bundle](https://github.com/lanthaler/HydraBundle), with that it is possible to do something like this.